# Seaborn how to add number of samples per category in sns.catplot

Tags: pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science

I have a catplot drawing using:

```
s = sns.catplot(x="level", y="value", hue="cond", kind=graph_type, data=df)
```

[image]

However, the size of the groups is not equal: 
"`Minimal`" has n=12 samples , and "`Moderate`" has n=18 samples.

How can I add this info to the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually calculate the sizes and add them to xticklabels, something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
cnts = dict(exercise['time'].value_counts())
key = list(cnts.keys())
vals = list(cnts.values())

g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind",order=key,
            data=exercise, kind="box")
g.set_axis_labels("", "pulse")
g.set_xticklabels([(key[i]+'\n('+str(vals[i])+')') for i in range(len(key))])
plt.show()
```

[image]